# select a division with specific class and specific name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've bunch of divisions with class `abc` and `name` attribute of same class is being set by `php`, it could be any thing between 0 to 5. I want to select divisions with class name abc and name as 0 and set background color as red, again class abc and name 1 background color as green like this for all classes. now the problem is how to select this combination. is there any way like we can select calss:

`$('div').is('.abc')`

Comment: i believe the proper way to select is by setting the proper css classes to match your criteria.

Comment: DIV elements don’t _have_ a `name` attribute in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div.abc')
```

selects all divs with class 'abc'

```
$('div.abc[name="myName"]')
```

selects all divs with class 'abc' and attribute name="myName"

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: yeah I know that..but how to select name attribute combination with it..sir read the question once again.. :)

Comment: @BharatSoni: your question isn't particularly clear as it stands. Maybe you could add the HTML code you're working with, and be more clear about what you're trying to achieve. As far as I can tell Antonis has answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

To select `div` with both `class` and `name` attribute combination just try:

```
$('div.abc[name="some_name"]')
```

### But `name` attribute for `div` is not allowed. **[READ IT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962070/attribute-name-not-allowed-on-element-div-at-this-point)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.abc').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('name') == 'yourName'){ // Do stuff }
});
```

or if you want to check for class from name:

```
$('div.abc[name="myName"]').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('class') == 'yourClass'){ // Do stuff }
});
```