# How do I update the css of a jQuery object after using it in a wrapInner function?

Tags: jquery

I have a simplified div with some simplified styling:

```
<div id="divOne" style="width:400px;height:300px;background:#f00">
  This is my content to be wrapped.
</div>
```

I want to create a jQuery object and style it after it's been attached.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var divTwo = $('<div \>').css('background','#0f0');
  $('#divOne').wrapInner(divTwo);
  divTwo.css('background','#00f');
});
```

The inner div should have a blue background, not green.
The strange part is, I can call an `alert(divTwo.css('background'));` and it will tell me it's blue.

Comment: which one of them? and why do you create the div with one color and then change it immediately afterwards?

Comment: The immediate color change is just an easy effect to see for purposes of demonstration.

Comment: what's wrong with setting the color before the `wrapInner()` call? I believe `wrapInner()` creates new elements with the specified structure, it doesn't append the passed elements, that's why you code is not working, `divTwo` is never inserted in the DOM

Comment: Thanks for explaining that `wrapInner()` creates new elements that aren't tied to my object; that clearly explains the behavior I've been seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. This looks like a quirk of jquery, where the style of the object you created isn't being cloned during the wrapInner function. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#divOne').wrapInner('<div/>').find('div').css('background','#00f')
});
```

or this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#divOne').wrapInner('<div style="background:#00f"/>')
});
```

Comment: I never thought to use `.find()`. With it I can easily reassign divTwo to the new element created by `wrapInner()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without the name attribute

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#divOne').wrappInner('<div\>');
   $('#divOne').children('div').css('background','#0f0')//blue color
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First attach the div to dom then apply styles.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#divOne').wrappInner('<div name="innerDiv" \>');
  $('[name=innerDiv]').css('background','#0f0')//blue color
});
```

Comment: name attribute in a div? you should use a class instead

Comment: My project uses this code inside a stateful plugin which will be applied to multiple elements. I would prefer to reference the newly created element through a jQuery object rather than an arbitrary id or name attribute.

Comment: koala_dev: class should be used for specifying styles ,name attribute is used specifically for getting handle and it performs better

Comment: @Farhan your statement is not true, classes are not only for styling purposes plus the w3c specifically states that there's no name attribute for div elements [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962070/attribute-name-not-allowed-on-element-div-at-this-point)

Comment: @koala_dev I didnt knew that as per w3c name attribute is not present for div ,but i have used the name attribute for divs in the past and it works perfectly.