# Access a div color-picker element through form controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, color-picker

I am using this [library](https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker) in order to add a color picker feature to my AngularJS app.
I would like to allow my client to use a color, which will then appear before him as small square div, with rounded corners(not the hex of the color, as my users are not technological).
The problem comes, when I want to allow my users to restore their previous selection, in case they don't like their current one(this info is stored in a service).

I would like to access the $pristine, and $dirty attributes of the div that the colorPicker directive is applied on, the problem is that giving a name to a div, is not valid HTML markup.

Is there an 'Angular way' to do that(using built in $pristine and $dirty) or would I have to hack my way through this by storing a Boolean flag in my service?.

```
<form name="designForm">
        <div class="formLine">
            <div class="miniFieldContainerSettings">
                Background Color
            </div>
            <div class="mediumFieldContainerSettings">
                <div data-colorpicker name="bgColor" class="colorSample" ng-model="model.formData.settings.background_color" data-ng-style="{backgroundColor : model.formData.settings.background_color}"><!--CANNOT GIVE A NAME ATTRIBUTE TO A DIV-->
                </div>
                <span class="btn btn-link" data-ng-disabled="designForm.bgColor.$pristine" data-ng-click="model.setDefaultColor('bgcolor')">
                    Restore previous
                </span>
                <span class="btn btn-link" data-ng-click="model.setDefaultColor('bgcolor', true)">
                    Set default
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a name property on a `div` (or you can use `data-name` if  you prefer).

You're running into a similar problem datepicker had ([datepicker and ngForm's $pristine state for field](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/855)) which was resolved by adding a call to `$setViewValue`.

The issue is that a change in `$pristine` is only triggered by a call to `setViewValue()`.  Angular's controls, such as `input` call this function for you (as the ngModelController docs note [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController)) :

> **$setViewValue(value)**:  Update the view value.
>
> This method should be called when the view value changes, 
>   typically from within a DOM event handler. For example input 
>   and select directives call it.

Since you're using a `div` as a control you need to handle the call to `$setViewValue()` to trigger a change in `$pristine`.

We can do that by adding a directive that will use a `watch` to call `setViewValue()` on the color picker model whenever the value changes.  That will result in `$pristine` being updated:

```
myApp.directive('updateView', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue){
        if (newValue !== oldValue){
            controller.$setViewValue(newValue);
        }
      });
    }}
});
```

Lastly we add the new directive to your `div` so Angular will treat it like a control:

```
<div data-colorpicker name="bgColor" class="colorSample" ng-model="model.formData.settings.background_color" data-ng-style="{backgroundColor : model.formData.settings.background_color} update-view">
```

I've created an example of this working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/f6uRe/1/

To simplify the example I've triggered the same problem you had using an `input` that's outside the form instead of the color picker.  It shows the same underlying issue and solution, but is more generic so maybe it'll help others more easily see how this works.

Comment: Thanks for your time dave, although in my case the DIV **is the input element** (take a look at the color-picker library that I have used).

And unfortunately, 'name' attribute is not allowed to be used on a div element according to the spec:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962070/attribute-name-not-allowed-on-element-div-at-this-point

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

Comment: data-name works too if you prefer. ng-model isn't on that list either but it (or data-mg-model) are fine to use. html doesn't rule out the use of new attributes- those docs are just saying it doesn't use them itself (but prefixing with data will make you more standards compliant. You can see Angular using `name` as an element on a div in their docs here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController  amongst other places

Comment: And sorry I wasn't clearer- of course you're right that your div is being used as an input element. The issue is that input controls need to call $setViewValue for $pristine to be updated. Angular-ui datepicker had the same issue, which it also resolved by calling $setViewValue- I added the link to that issue in the answer- it's an interesting read. So, I think following the same approach as the Angular-ui team puts us on pretty firm ground here